# Codelite C++ build suddenly not working. ar can't find GL

Tags: c++, build, static-libraries, codelite, unix-ar

I've been writing a mediocre game engine using SFML and OpenGL. Up until recently it has been building without difficulties, except for my own typos, bad code, etc. I'm building it as a static library, so (as I understand it, please correct me if wrong) after the actual compilation Codelite uses `ar` to stuff all the .o outputs into a single .a file. This seems to be where the issue is occuring.

```
/usr/bin/ar rcu ./Debug/libNDjinn.a @"NDjinn.txt" "GL" "sfml-graphics" "sfml-window" "sfml-audio" "sfml-network" "sfml-system"
/usr/bin/ar: `u' modifier ignored since `D' is the default (see `U')
/usr/bin/ar: GL: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [NDjinn.mk:80: Debug/libNDjinn.a] Error 1
```

The rest of the build log is minimal and has no errors, only a warning about a switch statement not handling all cases, which was there when it was building correctly. I'm using clang++, but I have also tried g++ with no change.

I've seen some people having an issue where `ar` couldn't find the file marked with @. The solution in those cases was to disable that method of passing the input files, and have Codelite instead pass each file as a separate arg. I tried this as well, no luck.

I've verified that no demons have gone in and removed `/usr/include/GL` or indeed `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so` since the time it last worked.

Thank you

Comment: `"GL" "sfml-graphics" "sfml-window" "sfml-audio" "sfml-network" "sfml-system"` seems suspicious. in "Settings/Build settings.../templates" I got only `$(AR) $(ArchiveOutputSwitch)$(OutputFile) @$(ObjectsFileList)`.

Comment: I can't see templates in the Build settings, sorry. But line 80 of the makefile reads `$(AR) $(ArchiveOutputSwitch)$(OutputFile) $(Objects) $(ArLibs)`

Comment: Templates is under Compilers, (your selected compiler as gcc/clang).

Comment: That lines from Makefile doesn't match given output... I would have expected "libGL.so" instead of "GL". try to see from where GL comes from.

Comment: I've only got Tools, Patterns, Compiler Options, Linker Options, Switches, File Types, and Advanced. None of those has a Templates sub-section. The only place I can imagine GL comes from is what I've put in the Libraries field for the Linker in project settings.

Comment: Then probably the tab Templates has been added in more recent version of Codelite...

Comment: As you have the generated makefile, you might check directly the commandline, see if changing GL to libGL.so or removing it fix the issue.

Comment: Removing all the libraries from the linker settings seems to have fixed the problem. I wonder how it was working before... Thank you for your help!